# TypeError while doing replace() on encoded BeautifulSoup result in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, str-replace

Trying to encode the text output received after parsing HTML data through BeautifulSoup library in Python 3. Getting following error:

> ----> gmtext.encode('ascii', errors='replace').replace("?", "")
>
> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Here is the code implementation:

```
import urllib.request as urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

articleURL = "http://digimon.wikia.com/wiki/Guilmon"

page = urllib2.urlopen(articleURL).read().decode('utf8', 'ignore')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
gmtext = soup.find('p').text

gmtext.encode('ascii', errors='replace').replace("?", "")
```

So far, all answers I found regarding this error have been about some sort of file open error.

Comment: Both solutions seemed to work. Thanks all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=encode#str.replace) is a string function, but you're calling it after calling [`.encode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=encode#str.encode),
which returns ["a bytes-like object"](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-bytes-like-object) that you can't call `.replace()` on.

If you want to, you can do replacement before encoding like so:

```
gmtext.replace("?", "").encode('ascii', errors='replace')
```

Then it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

you can do replace with bytes (using `b` before the string) like:

```
gmtext.encode('ascii', errors='replace').replace(b"?", b"")
```